# Proguard keep class actionbarsherlock

Tags: java, android, obfuscation, actionbarsherlock, proguard

There was

```
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
```

in my proguard config. As proposesd by the Actionbarsherlock guys (see http://actionbarsherlock.com/faq.html).
But only after adding

```
-keep public class * extends com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment
```

the classes which extended SherlockFragment were kept and so I was able to use the Fragments.

Why?

Comment: I'm curious, have you updated your SDK tools to at least r20? Since June of this year they should have made using custom views in xml safe with proguard (http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html): `"Added automatic ProGuard support for the aapt -G flag. This change causes the build system to generate a temporary ProGuard keep-rules file containing classes that are referenced from XML files (such as custom views) and pass this to ProGuard at shrink-time."`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's assume you have the following fragment declaration, used in xml layout:

```
public class MyFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    …
}
```

MyFragment class isn't in `com.actionbarsherlock.*` package, so ProGuard will obfuscate class name. In order to keep classes, which might be used in xml layout, add these parameters:

```
# keep all classes that might be used in XML layouts
-keep public class * extends android.view.View
-keep public class * extends android.view.ViewGroup
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

Comment: can you take a look at the comment I left the OP? I thought that as of SDK tools r20 that custom views were already safe to use with proguard.